# Installing Smart Switch to Gas Fireplace Switch

Tags: electrical, natural-gas

I'm trying to add a smart switch to replace our gas fireplace on off switch. The fireplace switch is nonpowered, but there is power for a light in same switch box. The smart switch requires power in order to power itself, which I assume it would normally draw from the circuit it's switching. But since it's a non powered circuit it can't. I believe I'd need to install a relay and tap off the light switch power to run the smart switch, and then hook the original wires from the switch to the relay, that the smart switch would then control. Can you let me know if my assumption is correct and what relay I'd need, preferably a link.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'd be worried about modifying the wiring of a gas appliance; there are all sorts of ways you could earn yourself a Darwin award.

Comment: Why do you want smart-switch control of the fireplace?

Comment: So it can be turned off and on remotely. From what I've learned the switch only has mV running through it powered by the thermister(?).  Completing that circuit just tells the fireplace to turn on, has nothing to do with ignition or pilot, pilot runs regardless. Pilot is actually what powers it.

Comment: Looking for the same except that I do NOT have power in the box besides the one coming from the thermopile... I doubt this power is good enough for the smart switch to connect to wifi.

Comment: Do you have power that you can get to the box? I figured this out, and works perfectly, but it will require normal 120 voltage